# how can I extend material ui theme type and modify existing types in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-design

I know that we can extend the `material ui` `theme` type and add new property like [this](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme):

for example adding `appDrawer` would be like this:

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    appDrawer: {
      width: React.CSSProperties['width']
      breakpoint: Breakpoint
    }
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    appDrawer?: {
      width?: React.CSSProperties['width']
      breakpoint?: Breakpoint
    }
  }
}
```

But My question is How can I modify existing properties for example I want to change `grey` property of `palette` to be like this:

```
createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    grey: {
      light: "#f7f7f7",
      main: "#e1e1e1",
      dark: "#c2c2c2"
    }
  })
```

But above code would give me this error:

```
Type '{ light: string; main: string; dark: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Color>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'light' does not exist in type 'Partial<Color>'.
```

so I want to extend the `grey` color to accept these values `{ light: string; main: string; dark: string; }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used a workaround and put all my custom properties in side a `custom` key like this:

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme" {
  interface Theme {
    custom?: {
      palette?: {
        grey?: PaletteColorOptions;
      };
    };
    newProp?: whateverTypeItIs
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    custom?: {
      palette?: {
        grey?: PaletteColorOptions;
      };
    };
    newProp?: whateverTypeItIs
  }
}
```